# Why do the 'colors' of liquids in differently sized glass cylinders appear similar despite varying absorption rates?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, reflection, absorption, lightning

For some liquids, such as cooking oil, I have observed that when filling two glass cylinders (with lids) of different diameters (e.g., one with a 5 cm diameter and another with a 10 cm diameter) with the same liquid, they 'look the same' to the naked eye. Intuitively, I would expect the absorption of light to be different in each cylinder due to the different path lengths the light travels through the liquid.

*Why does the absorption not appear to be significantly different in these two cases? (in the sense that both look approximately the same color and darkness).*

For other liquids, the situation may or may not be the same. In a colloid like milk, I would likely observe the same when looking at both cylinders. In a solution, for example, CuSO4, maybe not.

I would like to know, in each case, *what the main mechanisms are that determine what one observes and how much they contribute* (absoption, reflextion, scattering). By "how much", I mean something qualitative, such as "mostly, little, insignificant, etc.". In the case of a not highly concentrated dissolution, is reflextion significant?

Regarding lighting, consider usual conditions, either in a room or outdoors.